# Sorting text columns from 2 files into a single file

Tags: powershell, columnsorting

I need to get a list of locally installed software from a PC.

I'm using the following piece of code for this :

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Format-Table -AutoSize > app32.txt
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Format-Table -AutoSize > app64.txt
```

Then I need a single list of installed software sorted by DisplayName column.
Trying to use:

```
cat apps*.txt |
    where {$_ -ne ""} |
    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression="DisplayName"} |
    sc all_apps.txt
```

But in fact the list is not sorted in alphabetic order at column DisplayName and also the result file contains empty strings which should not be included

Comment: Instead of using Format-Table at the end you should use Export-CSV. This way it's easier to use the data further on.

Comment: Consider exporting the data initially as a CSV, and then using _that_ as the input for sorting and merging. PowerShell passes _objects_ through the pipeline, not text, and attempting to save data as text and then reprocess it is ... less good and often more problematical ... than preserving the object structure until you're actually presenting the data for a human to read.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Format-Table` like that.  `Format-Table` is for presenting information to the user, not presenting information to other commands.  It turns the output into a string instead of objects that PowerShell can manipulate.

Try:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Export-Csv -Path app32.csv -NoTypeInformation

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Export-Csv -Path app64.csv -NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv app32.csv, app64.csv |
    Where-Object { -not [System.String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_.DisplayName) } |
    Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
    Export-Csv -Path all_apps.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or, alternately:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
    Where-Object { -not [System.String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_.DisplayName) } |
    Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Export-Csv -Path app64.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |  export-csv app32.csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | export-csv app64.csv -NoTypeInformation

$softwarelist = import-csv -Path ".\app32.csv"
$softwarelist += import-csv -path ".\app64.csv"

$Softwarelist | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
```

Basically I used `export-csv` instead of just writing it to a txt file, this allows powershell to use `import-csv` and when it brings it in it recognises the different properties; when it gets the content from a .txt it just reads in a big ol' string.

Using `+=` we can add both files together and then just `sort-object` on them to display them how you like.

Edit: I should add you could skip writing them out as a CSV and instead just store them in a variable and use that.  Something like:

```
$softwarelist = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
$softwarelist += Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate

$Softwarelist | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
```